# Can we calculate the total harmonic distortion of an oscillator directly from ezwave?

Tags: oscillator, spice, pspice

Can we calculate the total harmonic distortion of an oscillator directly from ezwave?
If yes, then please tell how to calculate it.
Else what are the approaches to calculate THD of an oscillator.

Comment: **If** I answered you: **No that's impossible** would you believe that? Would you ask **why**? Your first step is to forget about formulas and **think** about what harmonic distortion really is. How does it manifest itself? If I gave you a box with an oscillator that has some unknown harmonic distortion, how would you measure that distortion? What equipment would you use? (Don't answer: a distortion meter).

Answer (score 0):

open up the spectrum analyzer, all the compare the power of the fundamental with the power of the whole signal, the difference is harmonic distortion. (and noise)